# What does the number next to your log in mean

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-connection

For example, when I open a connection, at the top of it it says "EXMPL\jsmith2(99)".  This is also shows at the bottom right of the screen, after the server and before the database.  What does the (99) mean?

thanks

Comment: It's the process ID (spid). Run `sp_who` and you should be able to match it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the [`spid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx) (process id). You can match if up by running

```
sp_who 'jsmith2'
```

Or, using your process id of 99, find the user:

```
sp_who '99'
```